# Storing a program config file at /etc vs at the program directory?

Tags: linux, standards, configuration-managment

On Linux: What would be a better standard if I have a project (i.e. a webserver) at /go/src/webserver - to store the config file at the same directory, or at the /etc directory (/etc/webserver/config)?

Also is it a bad standard to have the executable build file at the source directory (/go/src/webserver/webserver) rather than at a /bin or /usr/bin location? Why if so?

I'm talking about a personal project, not something someone else did.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is normally done is to leave the hierarchy at `/` (`/usr`, `/bin`, `/etc`) to the packet manager of the distro, and to install other software elsewhere, e.g. under `/usr/local` (which then again as `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/etc`, ...), or `/opt`, and so on.

Also, typically software intended to be installed on a system checks multiple location for configuration files, e.g. `/etc/`, `$HOME` and so on.

If you are talking about a project of your own, which is not packaged, and is not intended to be installed on other people's machines, none of this matters.

In particular, if you plan to mix your source with the executable, none of this matters, either.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about my own project